# Crafty.js bind not working in Firefox 24.0

Tags: firefox, bind, craftyjs

I have a very simple Crafty.js script working in Chrome.

in my component file I have this component:

```
Crafty.c('PlayerCharacter', {
init: function() {
var playerRef = this;
playerRef.bind("KeyDown", function(e) 
  {
      if (playerRef.isDown('LEFT_ARROW')) {
          playerRef.x=playerRef.x-16;
          myPlayer.sendMessage("LEFT");
      } else if (playerRef.isDown('RIGHT_ARROW')) {
          playerRef.x=playerRef.x+16;
          myPlayer.sendMessage("RIGHT");
      } else if (playerRef.isDown('UP_ARROW')) {
          playerRef.y=playerRef.y-16;
          myPlayer.sendMessage("UP");
      } else if (playerRef.isDown('DOWN_ARROW')) {
          playerRef.y=playerRef.y+16;
          myPlayer.sendMessage("DOWN");
      }
  });  
},
});
```

And then in my start function of the game, I have :

```
Crafty.e("2D, DOM, Color, Keyboard, Mouse, PlayerCharacter")
  .attr({x: 20*16, y: 20*16, w: 16, h: 16})
  .color('rgb(255,0,0)');
```

As mentioned the **Player Character** displays and moves as expected in Chrome, however in Firefox it simply displays initially and does not move. There are no errors generated.

If anyone has any ideas or ideas on how to debug this (currently using Firebug, with limited success).

BTW: the following alternate code also works in Chrome and not in Firefox

```
Crafty.c('Actor', {
  init: function() {
   this.requires('2D, Canvas, Grid');
  },
});

Crafty.c('PlayerCharacter', {
  init: function() {
   this.requires('Actor, Fourway, Color')
     .fourway(4)
     .color('rgb(20, 75, 40)');
  }
});
```

Comment: It would be easier to figure out what's going on if you set up a jsFiddle.  Where is `sendMessage` defined?

Comment: ***"the following alternate code also works in Chrome and not in Firefox"*** -- [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mCdUX/471/) that uses the Fourway code; it works fine for me in Firefox.  The only change I made from the code you posted was to not add DOM to the entity (since it already has "Canvas")

Comment: @starwed many thanks I will check out your fiddle, sendMessage should not have been posted as it is not relevant.

Comment: @starwed interestingly when I try your fiddle on my chrome browser it work fine, when I try it on my Firefox, it renders but does not move. Do you get it working on both Browsers your side ?

Comment: For me, it works fine in Firefox, Firefox Nightly, and Chrome.  This is on a Mac.  (Note that you do have to click on the correct frame of the fiddle to give it focus; that's true for all browsers.)  If the fiddle still isn't working for you in Firefox, I'd suggest restarting the browser in safe mode -- it might be that you have an extension messing with things.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu, weirdly a reboot seems to have sorted things out.

Comment: I'm in a situation where it works in Chrome but not in Firefox.  Wonder if I need to reboot too!